# Não consigo chamar uma função que está em outra pasta num arquivo js do javaScript, usei o import e informei o caminho mas não funcionou

Tags: javascript, importação

Módulo onde foi criado as funções

const numeros = () => [15, 101, 17, 0, 11, 21, 35]
const palavras = () => ["História", "Cultura", "Jornalismo", "Podcast"]
const numerosELetrasbooleans = () => [70, "Nacionalidade", "Poder", false, "Educação", 92, 1005, 69, true]

Módulo que desejo buscar as funções

import { numeros } from './exercicio1/script.js'

console.log(numeros)

Erro:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver usando apenas arquivos JS você deve abrir o terminal na pasta do projeto e executar o comando `npm init -y` (para isso, o node deve estar instalado na sua máquina), com esse comando executado será gerado em seu projeto um arquivo `package.json`, dentro desse arquivo terão algumas coisas, dentre elas você deve criar mais uma chave e valor, a chave `"type"` deve ter o valor `"module"`, com isso já deve funcionar.

Se você tem um arquivo `index.html` em seu projeto você não precisa rodar o comando que citei acima, basta na importação do arquivo JS você adicionar o atributo `"type"` dessa forma (exemplo): `<script src="arquivojs.js" type="module"><script/>` no lugar de arquivojs.js coloque o seu arquivo JS principal.

E antes de tudo, verifique se você está exportando o que deseja importar, exemplo:

```
export const numeros = () => [
    15, 101, 17, 0, 11, 21, 35
];

export const palavras = () => [
    "História", "Cultura", "Jornalismo", "Podcast"
];

export const numerosELetrasbooleans = () => [
    70, "Nacionalidade", "Poder", false, "Educação", 92, 1005, 69, true
];
```

Comment: Sou novo no JS e não estava fazendo o export mesmo, porém coloquei agora e aparece erro nessa parte do export ai Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export', e muito obrigado por me ajudar na primeira parte